# Remove prefix and suffix from order create page in backend

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping-address, billing-address

I want to remove suffix and prefix field in billing and shipping address when i create order from backend.

can anyone help me how to do this

Answer (score 0):

im doing this by override app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Sales\Order\Create\Form\Abstract.php in local folder

put this code at line number 147.

```
if($attribute->getAttributeCode()=='prefix' || $attribute->getAttributeCode()=='fax' || $attribute->getAttributeCode()=='suffix'  || $attribute->getAttributeCode()=='vat_id' || $attribute->getAttributeCode()=='middlename' )
            {
                continue;   
            }
```